# Why does assigning to $path break my $PATH in zsh?

Tags: macos, zsh, environment-variables

General guidance (e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826442/mkdir-command-not-found-in-bash-script)) is to use lowercase var names in shell scripts so-as not to conflict with important shell env vars like `PATH`.

However, today I learned that the $PATH var on MacOS is *case-insensitive*

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

$ path=test      

$ echo $PATH
test
```

It's certain not a general thing:

```
$ x=a          

$ echo $X
```

I assume its somehow related to the case-insensitive filesystem, but I haven't found a reasonable explanation yet of how this leaks into the variable name case-sensitivity.

The general takeaway is "don't use `path` as a var name", but I'm still wondering if someone can explain this surprising behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In contrast to `bash` or other shells, `zsh` (also `csh` & `tcsh`) provide the contents of the `$PATH` variable as an array in `$path`:

```
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ echo $PATH                 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ echo $path[2]
/usr/local/bin
```

While this could be useful in some situations, it is against the typical naming convention (*all UPPERCASE*) of environment variables on POSIX compliant systems, as usually you can freely use most lowercase variables in a script.

Note that the variables are still case-sensitive:

```
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ pAtH=foo          
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
╭─user@machine ~/test ‹master●› 
╰─$ echo $pAtH   
foo
```

As most scripts get written for `bash` and `zsh` incorporates a lot of such small in-obvious differences which sometimes bastardize the usability or portability to other systems, I tend to declare `bash` as the interpreter in the shebang of scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: Good answer! Yet another “gotcha” that is keeping me in the Bash world for now.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I love zsh with omz for manually using the shell! There are amazing autocomplete plugins and possibilities that make using it so much faster! But for scripts I stay with bash, as I even had problems with simple loops and I don't want to adjust each script for my machines where I use zsh.